# How to recursively resolve dependencies in a Maven 2 plugin

Tags: maven-2, maven, maven-plugin

I'm writing a Maven 2 plugin which must iterate over all project dependencies and recursively over all dependencies of these dependencies. Up to now I only managed to resolve the direct dependencies with this code:

```
for (Dependency dependency : this.project.getModel().getDependencies())
{
    Artifact artifact = this.artifactFactory.createArtifact(
        dependency.getGroupId(),
        dependency.getArtifactId(),
        dependency.getVersion(),
        dependency.getScope(),
        dependency.getType());
    this.artifactResolver.resolve(
         artifact,
         this.remoteRepositories,
         this.localRepository);

    ....
}
```

How can I do the same recursively so I also find the dependencies of the dependencies and so on?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A) Don't use
    `project.getModel().getDependencies()`,
    use [`project.getArtifacts()`](http://maven.apache.org/ref/2.2.1/maven-project/apidocs/org/apache/maven/project/MavenProject.html#getArtifacts%28%29)
    instead. That way you automatically get the transitive dependencies. To enable that: Mark your mojo as

- `@requiresDependencyResolution compile` or
- `@requiresDependencyCollection compile`

(see the [Mojo API Specification](http://maven.apache.org/developers/mojo-api-specification.html) for reference).

B) Do you really want to use the legacy dependency API? Why not [use the new Maven 3 Aether API](http://www.sonatype.com/people/2011/01/how-to-use-aether-in-maven-plugins/)?

Comment: A) I already tried getArtifacts() but it was always returning an empty set. So I simply missed this annotation. Works great now, thanks! B) Currently I have to support Maven 2. This will hopefully change soon.

Comment: Dear unknown downvoter, perhaps you would like to specify what you don't like about this answer?

Comment: +1 this was the finishing touch to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11341783/accessing-classes-in-custom-maven-reporting-plugin